# Unquoting construction in contextual-eval in The Joy of Clojure

Tags: clojure

The following code is from chapter 8.1.1 of (the second edition of) *The Joy of Clojure* by Fogus, Houser:

```
(defn contextual-eval [ctx expr]
  (eval
   `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k `'~v]) ctx)]   ; Build let bindings at compile time
      ~expr)))

(contextual-eval '{a 1, b 2} '(+ a b))
;;=> 3
(contextual-eval '{a 1, b 2} '(let [b 1000] (+ a b)))
;;=> 1001
```

I do not really understand the meaning of the construction `` `'~v ``. Can somebody please elaborate on that?

In the book, it is only said that

> The bindings created use the interesting `'~v pattern to garner the value of the built
>   bindings at runtime.

For example

```
(contextual-eval '{a 1, b 2} '(+ a b))
```

is expanded to

```
(let [a '1 b '2] (+ a b)))
```

and I don't understand *why* those quotes are introduced, what they are good for.

Also, we have the following behaviour:

```
(contextual-eval '{a 1, b (+ a 1)} '(+ a b))
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to java.lang.Number

(defn contextual-eval' [ctx expr]
  (eval
   `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k v]) ctx)]
      ~expr)))

(contextual-eval' '{a 1, b (+ a 1)} '(+ a b))
;=> 3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That expression uses almost all of the special line-noise-looking symbols available in Clojure, so it's worth picking it apart:

- `` ` `` is a reader-macro for "syntax-quote"
  "syntax-quote" is special among the reader macros because you can only call that function via it's short form. You can't for instance call something like `(syntax-quote something-here )` instead you would write `` `something-here ``. It provides a rich set of options for specifying what parts of the expression after it should be evaluated and which should be taken literally.
- `'`Is a reader-macro shortcut for the `quote` special form. It causes the expression that it wraps not to be evaluated, and instead to be treated as data. If you wanted to write a literal `quote` form without evaluating it, you could write `` `'something `` to get `` `(quote something) `` as the result. And this would cause the resulting quote expression not to be evaluated, just returned as is without running it yet.
- `~` is a part of the syntax of syntax-quote (it's "quote" with a syntax) that means "actually let this part run" so if you have a big list that you want taken literally (not run right now), except you have one item that you really do want evaluated right now, then you could write `` `(a b c ~d e f g) `` and d would be the only thing in that list that gets evaluated to whatever it's currently defined to be.

So now we can put it all together:

`` `'~ `` means "make a quote expression that contains the value of v as it is right now"

```
user> (def v 4)
#'user/v
user> `'~v
(quote 4)
```

And on to the motivation for this fancyness:

```
(contextual-eval '{a 1, b 2} '(+ a b))
```

seems like just adding some extra thinking without any benefit because it's basically just quoting the values 1 and 2. Since these are proper "values" they never change anyway.

Now if the expression was instead:

```
(contextual-eval 
  '{a (slurp "https://example.com/launch?getCode")
    b the-big-red-button} 
  '(press b a))
```

Then it would make more sense to be careful about **when** that particular bit of code runs. So this pattern is about controlling which phase of a programs life actually runs the code. Clojure has several "times" when code can run:

- at macro-evaluation time: while the code is being formed. (side effects here require much forethought).
- when your namespaces are loading: this is when forms at the top level run. This often happens when you start you program and before `main` is invoked.
- things that run as a result of running `main`

ps: the above definitions are tailored to the context of this question and not intended to use the "official" terms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what you wrote is precisely what I already understood ;). What I don't understand is *why* the authors introduce that quoting at all. For example, <code>(contextual-eval '{a 1, b 2} '(+ a b))</code> gets expanded to <code>(let [a '1 b '2] (+ a b))</code>. What are those quotes ('1 and '2) good for?

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: I should add that these forms come up extremely rarely in normal clojure code, if they ever do. It's good to understand them and think carefully about what you are doing if you find yourself actually using them.

Comment: I still don't really get it :(. Am I right that we would achieve the same result with (contextual-eval' '{a '(slurp "https://...") b 'the-big-red-button} '(press b a)), with the definition of contextual-eval' to be found above (in my question)? Your example evaluates to (eval (let [a '(slurp "http://...") b 'the-big-red-button] (press a b))), doesn't it? I don't understand what you mean in your last paragraph: if we used contextual-eval' instead of contextual-eval, why would the time when the code is executed change? Thanks a lot for your effort!